# How to parse an RSS feed in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, rss, rss-reader

There aren't any decent video on Youtube on how to parse an RSS feed in RN. However, while I was searching for a solution on Google, I found this `react-native-rss-parser` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rss-parser).

It has this usage example:

```
import * as rssParser from 'react-native-rss-parser';

return fetch('http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
  .then((rss) => {
    console.log(rss.title);
    console.log(rss.items.length);
  });
```

How do I parse the feed into an array? For example:

`constants/Stories.js`

```
export const HomeScreenStories = ([
  {
    pic: rss.items[0].imageUrl ,
    title: rss.items[0].title,
    caption: rss.items[0].description,
  }
])
```

***UPDATE***

`constants/Stories.js`

```
import shuffleArray from '../utils/shuffleArray'
import * as rssParser from 'react-native-rss-parser'

export const HomeScreenStories = ([
    pic: rss.items[0].imageUrl,
    title: rss.items[0].title ,
    caption: rss.items[0].description,

    /* HOW DO I PARSE THE RSS FEED INTO HERE??? */
])
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement it with their example? `rss.items` is probably the array you are looking for

Comment: yes, but when I run `expo start` it shows: "Can't find variable rss"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Axios in my implementation, but any request library should work. Or just fetch.

```js
import * as rssParser from 'react-native-rss-parser';
async componentDidMount() {
  const res = await axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'text'
  });
  try {
    const parsed = await rssParser.parse(res.data);
    this.setState({ rssFeeds: parsed.items });
  } catch(err) {
    .....
  }
}
```

EDIT: Updated with propose of solution

```js
return fetch('http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then(async (responseData) => {
    const rss = await rssParser.parse(responseData);
    console.log(rss.title);
    console.log(rss.items.length);
  });
```